# How to use the call operator to pass parameters to another PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that collects the parameters into an array and then tries to call an executable with those arguments.

```
param(
    [String] $FileName,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]] $Arguments
)

& $FileName $Arguments
```

This works great when calling simple executables, but throws and error when trying to call another PowerShell script that expects a number of parameters.

Exception:
**Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'a'. Cannot convert value
to type System.String.**

```
param(
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$a,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$b,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$c,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$d
)

Write-Output ($a + " - " + $b + " - "+ $c + " - "+ $d)
```

The number of parameters is variable.

My guess is that the call operator, seeing as the called file is a PowerShell script, tries to pass the array as an object instead of splitting the arguments.
I don't necessarily want to resort to **Invoke-Expression** as some arguments are provided by the user and it might pose a risk

**EDIT:**
I ended up doing something similar to what Jimmy Robitaille suggested.

````
$Command = "& $FileName"
foreach ($Arg in $Arguments) {
    $Arg = $Arg.Replace("`"", "```"")
    if ($Arg.Contains(' ') -or $Arg.Contains(';')) {
        $Command += " `"$Arg`""
    }
    else {
        $Command += " $Arg"
    }
}
Invoke-Expression $Command
````

Which is creating the argument string myself and executing it. I escaped the quotes from the parameters and surrounded parameters that contain spaces or semicolon with quotes.

Comment: you may want to look at `$PSBoundParameters` >>> PSBoundParameters - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/psboundparameters.html <<<, plus the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute, and at the `$Args` automatic variable.

Comment: Using the call operator `&`, PowerShell expects parameters and their corresponding arguments to be separated by a space. There should be no quotes around the parameter-argument pairs.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I looked at those but I can't see how they would help. They can be used by the caller script to gather the arguments to pass to the called script but this does not fix the issue.

Comment: @Krajla - ah! i misunderstood your intent. [*blush*] i see that you found a workaround ... good! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the indexes of the string array instead of passing the array itself, like so :

```
& $FileName $Arguments[0] $Arguments[1] $Arguments[2] $arguments[3]
```

Please note that the script will still fail if the number of arguments passed is lower than 4, and any parameter past the 4th one will be ignored. Some validation would also be helpful, but this will at least allow you to pass the parameters to the other script without an error.

EDIT:

Following clarification, without resorting to Invoke commands, the only way i can think of is to do something like this :

`` powershell.exe `"$FileName`" $($Arguments -join ' ') ``

You could try to parse the FileName and check if it's a PS1 or not, then either use the call operator or start powershell.

Comment: The number of parameters is variable, I will add clarification to the question.

Comment: I edited my answer, please do not hesitate to tell me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: This works but unfortunately leaves room for command injections. If I then imputed '-FileName ".\Test.ps1" a b c "d;cat .\Test.ps1"'  the output would be.

a - b - c - d
param(
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$a,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$b,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$c,
    [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$d
)

Write-Output ($a + " - " + $b + " - "+ $c + " - "+ $d)

Comment: But if this is the only way to make it work I will implement blacklisting on the arguments.

Comment: The call operator does not parse strings and do some special processing like adding quotes where needed, and from what I understand, the reason why code injection is not working with the call operator is the same reason why what you are trying to do will not work if the number of arguments is variable. The "powershell" command at least has the advantage to run the other script in a child scope as well, but code injection will indeed be possible.

Comment: For the call operator this (assuming a b c d are the 4 arguments) : 
```& $FileName $($Arguments -join ' ')```
is similar to this : 
```& $FileName "a b c d"```

Comment: The call operator actually adds quotes to arguments that have spaces in it, not sure if anything else.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested. I will edit the original question to include it. Any critic is appreciated of course.